# Reducing Item by -10 in Class Based View

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I have a button when clicked should reduce an Item by 10, it is possible to achieve using a function not as_view, please help on reproducing the same effect on a ListView

Views.py:

```
  def subs(request, pk):
    sw = get_object_or_404(Swimmers,id=pk)
    c_s = sw.sessions - 10
    sw.sessions = c_s
    sw.save()
    return render(request, 'accounts/modals/swimming/_vw_table.html', {'sw': sw})
```

URL:

```
path('subt/<int:pk>/', views.subs, name='subt'),
```

Template:

```
  <form id="post-form">
   <div class="col float-right">
   <button type="submit"  class="float-right btn btn-primary" id="saveBtn" name="button">REDUCE SESSION</a>
   </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear! Are you facing any errors or ..?

Comment: i get empty fields, Thank You